# Hibernate error with the configuration XML?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

this is the XML cofiguration of the proyect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basededatoshibernate?useSSL=false</property>
      <property name="connection.username">root</property>
      <property name="connection.password"> </property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

   </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

i tried chaging the password,"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" to "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd", the database name...

here is my obj class

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="pedidos")
public class Pedidos {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;
    @Column(name="nombre")  
    String nombre;
    @Column(name="productos")
    String productos;

    public Pedidos( String nombre, String productos) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.productos = productos;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getProductos() {
        return productos;
    }
    
    
    
    public void setProductos(String productos) {
        this.productos = productos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pedido [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", productos=" + productos + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

i tried chaging the name of the primary key, class name, atributes names...

here i have the method that connects with the DB

public static void Create(Pedidos pedido) {

```
    SessionFactory miFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Pedidos.class).buildSessionFactory();
    System.out.print("registo ingresado en la BD");
    Session miSession = miFactory.openSession();
    
    try {
        System.out.print("registo ingresado en la BD");
        miSession.beginTransaction();
        System.out.print("registo ingresado en la BD");
        miSession.save(pedido);
        System.out.print("registo ingresado en la BD");
        miSession.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.print("registo ingresado en la BD");
        miSession.close();
        
    }finally {
        miFactory.close();
    }
}
```

and the error...

> jun. 04, 2022 8:43:39 P. M. org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
> HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.33.Final jun. 04, 2022
> 8:43:40 P. M.
> org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>  INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
> {5.1.2.Final} jun. 04, 2022 8:43:40 P. M.
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
> (not for production use!) jun. 04, 2022 8:43:40 P. M.
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
> at URL
> [jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basededatoshibernate?useSSL=false]
> jun. 04, 2022 8:43:40 P. M.
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****,
> user=root} jun. 04, 2022 8:43:40 P. M.
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
> buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false jun. 04, 2022
> 8:43:40 P. M.
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections
>  INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
> jun. 04, 2022 8:43:40 P. M.
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator
> initiateService WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query
> metadata java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as
> the driver manager is not properly initialized

Comment: Your connection URL looks like you accidentally repeated parts of it. You have `jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basededatoshibernate?useSSL=false`. I am guessing you need `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basededatoshibernate?useSSL=false`. This change may not be sufficient to solve the underlying problem, but I think it is necessary.

Comment: Please try updating the connection URL as the above.